# JNDI not to find DataSource from SQLServer

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, jndi, connection-pooling

I have a MS SQLServer 2008 a database named: "conpool". and have created there a table with id, fullName and age. 
NoW i have implement in Java in Netbeans 7.3 and Tomcat 7.0.30 a Connection Pool to not bind everytime a Connection with my Database and i can just make Querys for my database.

My Connection Pool:

//------------------------Beginn JDBC Connection Pool ----------------------------------

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, NamingException {
    // Get DataSource

    Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
    System.out.println("Test1: a object from InitialContext has been created");

    Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    System.out.println("Test2: Context lookup was OKAY");

    //The JDBC Data source that was created in SQLServer
    DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/conpool");
    System.out.println("Test3: DataSource lookup with JNDI was successfully");
    System.out.println("JDBC Connecction Pool is created successfully");

    //-------------------------Ende JDBC Connection Pool--------------------------------------

    //Using a connection from the pool
    Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
    System.out.println("Test4: Datasource Connection was successfully");

    if (connection == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Error establishing connection!");
        //System.out.println("DBConnection Failed!!! ");
    }

    //Using the connection to access the database

    //--------------------------------Beginn der Queryprocess------------------------------------------

    String query = "SELECT * FROM conpool.dbo.Personen";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    System.out.println("Test5: All Object for a single Query are created");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(query));
    }
    //Connection will be closed
    connection.close();

    //-------------------------------Ende der Queryprocess--------------------------------------

   }
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
<description>Tomcat-ConnectionPooling with MS SQLServer</description>
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/conpool</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

my context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context  antiJARLocking="true" path="/ITWService">

<!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
<Resource name="jdbc/conpool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"

          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"

          username="dbo" password="" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

          url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=conpool"/>
</Context>
```

Now I am getting this kind of Error:

run:

Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.akapoor.itwservice.server.RestServer.main(RestServer.java:136)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Pls help me to solve my Problem. i will very thankful to you I am very confused. I tried everything but doesnt help .. Pls tell me where my problem is why I am not connecting to my database

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in a managed environment (like an application server) to just create an InitialContext without parameters.

As the code you posted has a main method I assume you have executed your code as a standalone application. But in your question you write that your application runs on a Tomcat, so you need to deploy it to your container and call it there.

Or is there a reason why you want to remotely access JNDI?

Comment: No how will its look like, what you are saying.. can you write a piece of code as example .. that will helps me a lot

Comment: The error message you posted means that the creation of the InitialContext failed. If you executed the same code in the Tomcat it would succeed.

Comment: How can I do this code in the Tomcat? How does the code look like and where should I do this?

Comment: Can you write a example for my Solution? then I can understand it besser -.-

Comment: [There's a full example in the Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)